# ThreeJS rotate coordinate axes of a FBX models arm

Tags: three.js

I would like to rotate the coordinate axes of specific segments of a .fbx model. E.g. as illustrated on the image I would like to rotate the coordinate axes of the right arm 90 degress around the Z-axis.

I can see that `THREE.Object3D.DefaultUp` can change the default coordinate system of an object, but I cannot apply it to the fbx segment objects.

Just to be clear, I dont want to rotate the mesh/arm, but only the coordinate axes that define the arms rotation. Is that possible?

[image]

I load the .fbx model and define the arm as so:

```
        // model
        const loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
        loader.load( '{{ url_for('static', filename='ybot.fbx') }}', function ( object ) {
            
            myObj = object;

            myObj.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child.isMesh ) {
                    child.castShadow = true;
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
                }
            });
            
            rightArm = myObj.getObjectByName('mixamorigRightArm');

            // Do the rotations here
            
            scene.add( myObj );
        });
    }
```

Comment: No, you cannot change the default coordinate system of WebGL. To do so, you'd have to rewrite the shaders, transform and camera matrices, and renderer that you're using. It would be much easier to simply modify your asset in a 3D editor to conform to the WebGL standard.

Comment: Actually the last part you mention is my question. I dont want to alter the default coordinate system of WebGL but of the asset. However, I would like to do it in WebGL instead of a 3D editior, and was wondering if that was possible. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Oh, I presume you could iterate through all the vertices [in the mesh's `BufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry) and change the x & y values from `[x, y, z]` to `[y, -x, z]`. Although this approach requires the rotation pivot to be at `[0, 0, 0]`, otherwise you'd have to take the pivot translation into account.